# Двумерный массив → Поменять местами столбцы

Tags: java, массивы

Даны двумерный массив (матрица) и два числа: i и j. Поменяйте местами столбцы с индексами i и j в матрице.

Вход содержит размеры матрицы n и m, не превышающие 100, затем элементы матрицы, затем индексы i и j.

Пример ввода 1:

```
3 4

11 12 13 14
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34

0 1
```

Пример вывода 1:

```
12 11 13 14
22 21 23 24
32 31 33 34
```

Мой вопрос: Почему мое решение не работает, а именно почему полностью не проходит присваивании array2 значение от array?? Голову сломал, простейший код, а с чего не работает не понятно.

Моё решение:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int a2 = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[a1][a2];

        for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a2; j++) {
                array[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }

        System.out.println();

        int i1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int i2 = scanner.nextInt();

        int[][] array2 = array;

        for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a2; j++) {
                if (j == i1) {
                    array2[i][j] = array[i][i2];
                }
                if (j == i2) {
                    array2[i][j] = array[i][i1];
                }
                System.out.print(array2[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int[][] array2 = array;` у вас `array` и `array2` - это один и тот же массив. Не копия, а прямо один и тот же. Делая вот такое `array2[i][j] = array[i][i2];` вы навсегда теряете то, что было записано по индексу `[i][j]`. Попробуйте написать функцию, которая меняет местами значения двух ячеек массива, и потом примените эту функцию на два столбика.

Comment: то что это один и тот же массив я понял по результату и то что теряю значение по индексу [i][j] тоже понял. Своим действием присваивания я надеялся, что присваиваю значения одного массива другому, а получается = не работает как присваивание и просто array2 становится ссылкой на array? Не подскажите где можно об этом почитать? Перерыл про массивы не звука о данном случае.

Comment: чтобы понять, что происходит вот тут `int[][] array2 = array;` вам надо ознакомиться со ссылочными типами в java. Ссылка - это как бумажка с адресом, то есть когда вы делаете вот так `int[][] array2 = array;` - вы просто создаете ещё одну бумажку, но с тем же адресом. И все операции, типа такой `array2[i][j] = 0;` происходят по тому же адресу, что и `array[i][j]=0`. Но это вам в вашей текущей задаче не надо, ваша задача легко решается без дополнительных ссылок на массивы и без дополнительных массивов.

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int a2 = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[a1][a2];

        for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a2; j++) {
                array[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }

        int i1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int i2 = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
            int tmp = array[i][i1];
            array[i][i1] = array[i][i2];
            array[i][i2] = tmp;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

буду грызть глубже ссылочные типы ))
p.s. исправлено согласно поправкам от tym32167

Comment: вам даже не надо тут 2 цикла, вам нужен только цикл по строчкам, а индексы столбцов вы и так знаете. Потому вы можете просто удалить это `for (int j = 0; j < a2; j++)` и вместо `j` использовать `i1` в коде.

Comment: благодарю за комментарии

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {
            {11, 12, 13, 14},
            {21, 22, 23, 24},
            {31, 32, 33, 34}
    };

    swapColumns(arr, 0, 1);

    Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    // [12, 11, 13, 14]
    // [22, 21, 23, 24]
    // [32, 31, 33, 34]
}
```

```java
public static void swapColumns(int[][] arr, int column1, int column2) {
    Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(row -> {
        int temp = row[column2];
        row[column2] = row[column1];
        row[column1] = temp;
    });
}
```

---

Без использования временной переменной, для общего развития:

```java
public static void swapColumns(int[][] arr, int column1, int column2) {
    Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(row -> {
        row[column1] = row[column1] + row[column2];
        row[column2] = row[column1] - row[column2];
        row[column1] = row[column1] - row[column2];
    });
}
```

```java
public static void swapColumns(int[][] arr, int column1, int column2) {
    Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(row -> {
        row[column1] += row[column2];
        row[column2] -= row[column1];
        row[column2] = -row[column2];
        row[column1] -= row[column2];
    });
}
```